# Compare this date with Today

Tags: momentjs

I'm trying to compare this

```
    if (moment('YYYY-MM-DD').isSameOrBefore('2019-04-21')) {
    nCiclo("1")}
```

But for some reason it returns false when it should returns true, I don't understand why if I put

```
    if (moment('2019-04-21').isSameOrBefore('2019-04-21')) {
    nCiclo("1")}
```

Then it yes becomes true.

Comment: are you actually putting in ````YYYY-MM-DD```` into the moment function? If so, that's not an actual valid date...If you're trying to use the current time, just don't pass anything in, so it would be ```moment().isSameOrBefore...```